# bitcoin node startup daemon with created wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

When I restart the Bitcoin node, I would like to load the wallet I created in the "wallets" subdirectory.

1. bitcoin-cli createwallet "1"
2. bitcoin-cli listwallets -> result : "", "1"
3. bitcoin-cli -testnet stop
4. bitcoind -testnet -daemon
5. bitcoin-cli listwallets -> result : ""

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load a wallet using the `loadwallet` command.

To load the wallet named `1`, do

```
bitcoin-cli loadwallet "1"
```

In order to have that specific wallet always loaded, add to your `bitcoin.conf` file:

```
wallet=1
```

Comment: Is there any way I can load it when the node starts?

Comment: You add the `bitcoin.conf` line I mentioned in my answer.